# Creating writable resultsets in ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net, .net-2.0

The ADO.NET implementation of the .NET framework 2.0 beta 1 included a writeable resultset which was removed in the beta 2. The obvious reasons for this is that it would hog server resources to keep updateable cursors open on the server. However, this would be useful when used correctly; specifically when updating or inserting large numbers of records.

I'm aware of the bulk copy api now available, but there are still many uses for a writeable resultset, so I am interested in researching how it was implemented in beta 1, to determine the feasibility of re-implementing this in a new library.

I'm interested in hearing suggestions on how to do something similar (create a writable resultset) or how to research this further, with or without access to the old framework.

Or, is there a way I can obtain the old framework so I can look into seeing how this was done?

Answer (score 2):

You should update the app to not use the deprecated API from that beta .net framework.  Typically, deprecated APIs have equiavalent and often better ways of doing the same thing.

Beta releases are to get feedback (issues etc...) back to the framework team but also for users to get a preview of what is coming so they can update their app.  You should avoid depending on a deprecated API for that long from an old beta framework.  Betas are by definition in transition ...

Comment: I'm aware of all this. I need to compare framework sdk versions for a specific reason.

Comment: @boomhauer - We cannot help you.  We cannot give you a legal link to the beta in question.

Answer (score 2):

The license for .NET 2 beta 1 and beta 2 (any beta, including RC's) has expired many years ago.  You cannot legally use it anymore.  Even if you find it, you will be violating the law if you use it.

Microsoft's beta licenses are always structured such that they expire when the final gold version ships.  They typically give you a grace period to upgrade, but 6 years is well beyond any grace period.

Comment: I'm aware of all this. I need to compare framework sdk version for a specific reason.

Comment: @boomhauer - We cannot help you.  We cannot give you a legal link to the beta in question.